# ScrollView isScrollEnabled loop fail in webView

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, boolean, scrollview

I am trying to do a "while" into a webView which contains a Twit, but it never ends. When the scroll is not enabled anymore (because it reaches the height it needs), it should stop and quit the "while", what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
while webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled == true {
                        
    webView.frame.size.height += 50
    self!.heightContraint.constant += 50
                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the observer to check the conditions of webViews ScrollView

in ViewDidLoad:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(self.batteryLevelChanged),
    name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)
```

setting function:

```
@objc private func batteryLevelChanged(notification: NSNotification){     
    
if webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled == true {
webView.frame.size.height += yourSize
self!.heightConstraint.constant += yourSize

} else {
//Do some Stuff if needed and don't forget to set static state of webView here;)

}
```

This is the way I prefer to use, by the way you are also missing on ELSE in your code